# How to make the datagridview line text in bold when I pick a row?

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I make the datagridview line text in bold when I pick a row?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Handle the [CellFormatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx) event of the [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) and apply a bold style to the font if the cell belongs to a selected row:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
  var dataGridView = sender as DataGridView;
  if (dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Selected)
  {
    e.CellStyle.Font = new Font(e.CellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
    // edit: to change the background color:
    e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Coral;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help !. and how to change the BackColor of the row ?

Comment: Is it possible to mark with bold only some of the words in the cell, not whole cell? I need this functionality for showing highlights, but I don't know how to implement this? Is it possible at all?

Comment: @FrenkyB: See the article [RichTextBox Cell in a DataGridView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31823/RichTextBox-Cell-in-a-DataGridView) on Code Project, but there seems to be performance issues... Maybe be if your data is read only it might be acceptable.

Comment: I got a null reference error when the grid was empty so I used `row.Cells[1].Style.Font = new Font( blahblahDataGridView.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Bold);` - but I also had to set a default font for the DataGridView.

Answer (score 1):

After loading the contents in Datagrid, apply these event handlers to RowEnter and RowLeave.

```
private void dg_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle boldStyle = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
    boldStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
    dg.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle = boldStyle;
}

private void dg_RowLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle norStyle = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellStyle();
    norStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);
    dg.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle = norStyle;
}
```

Codes are not tested. But it should work fine.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle `SelectionChanged` event of dataGridView and set `cell` style.

Answer (score -2):

The below code will make the font under Bold style for the selected row. "Total" is the last row check in my code

```
protected void gvRow_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
 {
  if (e.Row.Cells[rowIndex].Text == "Total") 
  {
   e.Row.Font.Bold = true;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Its about DataGridView component, your is something else.

Comment: ok,My answer is based on GridView! what should i do now.. shall i delete my answer?