# Is it possible to fill a Datagrid source from a method call but only use parts of the returned list?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Sorry, very new to Datagrids. I like the idea of filling a Datagrid source from a method call like this:

```
AWin.PredicateStatementDataGrid.ItemsSource = Tactics.GeneratePredicateStatements();
```

But unfortunately, it's overwriting how I want the datagrid to look (I've manually set column headers and widths):

```
<DataGrid Name="PredicateStatementDataGrid" GridLinesVisibility="All"  HeadersVisibility="All">
         <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ID #" Width="35" IsReadOnly="True">
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Predicate Statement" Width="300" IsReadOnly="True">
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
         </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

But this is what the output looks like:
[image]

I don't want the method call to create a second set of columns and I really don't want IsBold displayed (I want to use it as a boolean to set bold type as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696300/how-to-make-the-datagridview-line-text-in-bold-when-i-pick-a-row)).

So, is it possible to fill a datagrid from a method call but only use some of the elements in the returned List? And is it possible to not overwrite my manually set columns and headers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Second set of columns" and "elements in the returned list" are both deliberately ambiguous, so this may not be precisely the answer you're asking for, but it *sounds like* you want to display *all* of the elements in the returned list, but only some of the properties for each. If so, set AutoGenerateColumns="False" on the DataGrid, and fill in `<DataGrid...><DataGrid.Columns>...` with the columns you want. Examples abound on Stack Overflow and elsewhere.

Comment: If I use AutoGenerateColumns="False" then the method call does not fill in the datagrid at all. I'm not trying to be 'deliberately ambiguous'. But, yes, I want to only display 2 of the 3 properties of the elements in the returned List.

Comment: That's because you are not binding your columns. Also you want DataGridTextColumn for text. See my answer.

Comment: @zetar To help me write more informative comments in the future, can you help me understand why you stopped reading my comment just before "and fill in"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set AutogenerateColumns to false. Then you need to bind the columns to the properties in your collection.

```
<DataGrid Name="PredicateStatementDataGrid" GridLinesVisibility="All"  
          HeadersVisibility="All" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBold}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Fontweight" Value="Bold"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID #" Width="35" IsReadOnly="True"
            Binding="{Binding ID}">
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Predicate Statement" Width="300" 
            Binding="{Binding Statement}">
            IsReadOnly="True">
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: There seems to be an error with the above code.. can't find it. But, overall, this is the solution.

Comment: Found the bug. Hey, thanks a million! This really helps!